Spatial relationships between cells of two layers - does the top layer influence the bottom layer?

data <- data.frame(
  Layer = c(rep("TopLayer", 9), rep("BottomLayer", 9)),
  CellNumber = rep(1:9, 2),
  Rows = rep(1:3, each = 3, times = 2),
  Columns = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),
  Organism_A = c(2384106527, 1536784094, 1539751217, 1523052513, 1590814987, 
                1352107649, 1489242422, 1324947256, 1436861411,
                28989707.78, 13804448.59, 9445083.257, 10938353.51, 6964463.102, 
                3054182.127, 25332055.04, 6898327.535, 6106191.811),
  
  Organism_B = c(2200824832, 689252420.8, 773417652.8, 781621554.2, 900596793.4,
                799927709.2, 877576655.6, 882006114.1, 1185177471,
                12995607.78, 3990189.403, 3478803.283, 4269672.447, 4336314.549, 
                1772615.585, 9455652.995, 2166266.218, 3354112.17),
  
  Organism_C = c(565141031.9, 407109923.1, 399919019.7, 515591332, 350369021.1, 
                124343494, 236922640.3, 315508071.3, 388405241.6,
                9021589.754, 1282827.48, 289038.1483, 1856107.588, 669560.0038, 
                402480.99, 16047493.08, 4076703.421, 2540274.561),
  
  Organism_D = c(13886816.39, 5917155.69, 9076079.724, 6364479.436, 6603299.193, 
                2377757.035, 3409059.65, 5316280.163, 7019860.52,
                589742.1374, 50374.84351, 24320.78487, 27717.46694, 33827.55107, 
                17236.38709, 2966871.601, 3383635.365, 243522.6605),
  
  Organism_E = c(81810916.23, 23506996.31, 33640850.07, 60426641.66, 39478621.87, 
                18547510.22, 28971068.71, 30003359.9, 29142667.22,
                13305779.94, 5571703.603, 2251696.156, 6018467.227, 1475516.435, 
                267636.2172, 20126618.14, 28724649.18, 7349550.19))

I have two layers on top of each other with 9 cells (Row 1:3 and Column A:C). Inside each cell there are values from 5 different organisms. I want to find out if there are connections between the cells on top of each other. In other words, are there spatial patterns? Does the Top Layer influences the Bottom layer?
Can can I accomplish this? Is this crosscorrelation? Is there a way to spatialy show similarities?
I can use R or Python.

The first thing to do is to plot the data. Arrange your data by organism, then by layer, and run a scatter plot of top vs. bottom (or vice-versa), for each organism. If there are relationships, they may be very clear, and we can find ways to quantify this. And if it looks like random data points...

Thanks! I already did that but I am not interested in the connection of the individual organisms (Organism_A Top compared to Organism_A Bottom). I would like to know if in there is a connection of the data (all Organismns) in CellA1-Top and the data in CellA1-Bottom.

What are the integer values you have for datapoints? They are huge (billions?). Are these counts? In any case, then add the values for all organisms in each cell, and again do a scatter plot. If you can see a relationship (correlation), then it is easy to calculate a statistic to characterize it (e.g. R, correlation coefficient). If your eyes can not see any pattern... (human brain is a fantastic pattern matching computer),

Thanks! The values are bacterial abundances, so very large numbers. I will do that.
I thought there would be way to see if OrganismA and B have a same pattern across the layers in terms of "Which cell contains the most"...

For that 2nd objective (does Organism A & B have the same pattern), then go back to my 1st suggestion; scatter plot (and compute correlation coefficients, and for that matter also try OLS regression -as a first step-) by organism. That will tell you if A & B (or C&D, etc.) vary according to some visible pattern.  Once you know that a) there is a pattern and b) what it may be, then c) quantify it, with some appropriate statistic is the easy step. Otherwise, you are hunting in the dark. My first ruke of statistic for my students: first, always plot your data...
